# Display port to DVI or Display port to HDMI, or VGA

Tags: external-display, ports

I know that there are a lot of questions about different ports for connecting a monitor, but i have one that i think is unanswered elsewhere.

I have a laptop with only a display port and VGA output.
I have a monitor with HDMI, DVI and VGA input
Its a 27 inch monitor, with 1980x1080 resolution, refreshing at 60hz
I am running intel graphics

In order to display on my external monitor, i need to either connect via VGA (which i am doing currently) or get a converter from display port to DVI or display port to HDMI. In theory i could also get a VGA converter to DVI/HDMI, but that would seem to be pointless.

What i am wondering is i) will converting display port to DVI/HDMI give me better quality than VGA; and if so ii) which conversion will give me the best results.

Any and all advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes HDMI and Display Port has the capability for higher resolutions then VGA or DVI

Comment: Usually the DP port is actually a DP++ port, which output TMDS signal natively as well. You can hence use a simple passive cable with DisplayPort on one end and either HDMI or DVI on the other end. I really don't see any reason to use VGA unless your sink does not have any kind of digital interface at all.

Answer (score 1):

For your monitor and resolution, HDMI and DVI will produce equal results. It will come down to price and availability.

Personally, I would go with DVI. That way, you have a free HDMI port open to use for something else in the future, like a Blu-ray player, Chromecast, Apple TV, etc.

Comment: Great, this is helpful thinking, but i just would like to be clear; in terms of quality: whether going from DP to HDMI or DVI makes no difference. Its just about the convenience of other connections that i might want to make in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Get a DisplayPort to HDMI [adapter](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=dp%20to%20hdmi%20adapter) or [cable](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=dp%20to%20hdmi%20cable).  The advantage of DP to HDMI is that it can carry sound as well.  If you choose to hookup the laptop to a HDTV, you will only need that one cable or adapter.

You do not want to use VGA.  Your laptop if converting digital video, to analog VGA, back to digital.  There is always a loss in quality that way.  It might not be much, but I can see a difference.